# MySQL query fails under IE6 only

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer-6

I have a shop site where users can add/edit to a cart from a displayed list of products. Pretty simple stuff. On my "Add to Cart" button, (this is by client request) a confirm box pops up and asks if the user wants to add more to their cart. If they don't, it goes to the cart page to check out, if they do want to add more, it just refreshes the same page.

The problem I'm having is AFTER they click something in the confirm box and when that page refreshes, somehow the SELECT query to query the products to bring them up again (the exact query it just did) breaks... only in IE6.

The query itself looks something like this:

```
  $query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT ProductID, Lang, MasterPack, ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, Restricted1, ProductCode, ProductDesc, UnitsInStock, Image, Chargeable, UnitPrice, PDFName FROM tblInventory WHERE Client='Tenneco' AND InventoryGroup IN($invGroupStr) ORDER BY ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, ProductDesc ASC LIMIT %s,50", GetSQLValueString($pg, "int"));
```

It breaks at around `$invGroupStr) AND ProductCategory='%s'` at the bracket. I am certain that $invGroup is set to something.

Query after the sprintf is this:

```
SELECT ProductID, Lang, MasterPack, ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, 
       Restricted1, ProductCode, ProductDesc, UnitsInStock, Image, 
       Chargeable, UnitPrice, PDFName 
FROM tblInventory 
WHERE 
    Client='Tenneco' AND InventoryGroup IN('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', '') 
ORDER BY ProductCategory, ProductSubCategory, ProductDesc ASC 
LIMIT 0,50
```

Is there something obvious that I should look into? This site was originally in PHP4 and is very poorly coded in general (I'm just tasked to take it over from what's already there).

Comment: Even facebook doesn't like IE6. you should really encourage your clients to upgrade their browser.

Comment: What do you mean by *breaks*?

Comment: @Jonathan MySQL errors out on a bracket in that query (specifically "IN($invGroupStr)") but it doesn't make sense why because the same query just ran before the button was pressed.

Comment: @magicianIam This client persisted me to have this shop run under 800x600 resolution. Pretty sure they are either running Windows 98 or on old Pentium 3. Long story short, not sure if I can force them to upgrade browser.

Comment: @adamzwakk Print the query out for us, after it's been passed through `sprintf`.

Comment: @adamzwakk WOW just WOW, most of our CSS people would curse that guy for running IE6. anyway for your problem i'm guessing your jquery or JS is not working well with IE6 does making it unable to process your query. i would suggest using IE6 for testing but i think they buried that browser somewhere. :D

Comment: @adamzwakk Print the query, please.

Comment: @adamzwakk Those two queries aren't the same.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Yes. (It might be worth noting that the query does not break in IETester under IE6 mode).

Comment: @adamzwakk The query you printed is not the same query that you shared when you posted this question. Which one *breaks* for IE6 users?

Comment: My bad, posted the wrong query the first time. Question updated. It's been a long day.

Comment: @adamzwakk This still can't be right. Your query has `"IN($invGroupStr) ORDER BY"` but you are saying the error is around `$invGroupStr) AND ProductCategory='%s'`. Your query doesn't go from the `IN()` collection to and `AND`. Are you sure you have the right query, or that you copied the right printed query?

Comment: @JonathanSampson Query runs fine in MySQL directly.

Comment: @adamzwakk `%s` in `sprintf` is for strings. I would encourage you to change your `LIMIT` clause to use an integer like `%d`. Also, are you in any position to test the success of these changes?

Comment: rule 1: whenever a client specifies IE6 as a requirement, tell him it doubles the price of the project. It certainly doubles the amount of work you'll have t do, so why not pass on the cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a dumb error. When the "add to cart" does the ajax request, it does it under the NOT www. domain, which IE6 treats as a new user and deletes the current user's session. Which then makes that $invGroup invalid, hence the query fails. Not sure why someone would set it up that way.

One day I will redo this entire site with proper PHP5... one day.

Thanks @Jonathan Sampson for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Queries don't run in the browser. It is *impossible* for IE to be the cause of a MySQL query failing since the query is run on *your* server, and not the client's browser.

Try printing out the errors associated with the *broken* query using [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php):

```
$result = mysql_query( $brokenQuery ) or die( mysql_error() );
```

Then work backwards from there.

Comment: Totally agree with this and I'm aware of that. But the issue only happens in IE6. I'm completely clueless why it's happening.

Comment: @adamzwakk The issue happens on your server - not in the browser. It may only happen with users of a certain browser, but that would have nothing to do with the structure of your query. Start by telling us what happens when it *breaks*, please.